# Смена размера шрифта одновременно в нескольких активити

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть несколько активити, к которых при нажатии на меню появляется seekBar и пользователь, перемещая ползунок, может поменять размер текста. 
В каждой из ативити реализован такой код

```
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    public static final String FONT_SIZE = "FONT_SIZE";
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        loadSizeFont();
}

  @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        sizeFont = progress;
        tv_text.setTextSize(sizeFont);
        saveSizeFont();    
    }
   @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {    
    }


 void saveSizeFont() {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPref.edit();
        ed.putInt(FONT_SIZE, sizeFont);
        ed.apply();    
    }

    void loadSizeFont() {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int size = (int) sharedPref.getInt(FONT_SIZE, 17);
        tv_text.setTextSize(size);  
        seekBar.setProgress(size);
    }
```

Если в активити 1 пользователь увеличил шрифт, потом переключился на активити 2, там нужно снова вызывать seekbar и двигать ползунок. Это не совсем удобно. Нужно, чтобы изменив размер размер в одном месте, он поменялся бы и в остальных необходимых активити. Подскажите, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Читать сохраненные SharedPreferences  в каждой активити.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно либо хранить данные в `SharedPreferences` и считывать их при необходимости, как вам уже посоветовали.

Можно сделать такой синглтон:

```
public class DataSaver {
    private static DataSaver dataSaver;
    private static final String PREFS = "prefs";
    private static final String T_SIZE = "size";

    private int textSize;

    public DataSaver get (Context ctx) {
        if (dataSaver ==null) dataSaver= new DataSaver(ctx);
        return dataSaver;
    }

    private DataSaver(Context ctx) {
        textSize = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(T_SIZE,17);
    }

    public int getTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }

    public void setTextSize(Context ctx, int textSize) {
        ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(T_SIZE,textSize).apply();
        this.textSize = textSize;
    }
}
```

В нужном месте/активности вызывать: `DataSaver.get(MyActivity.this).getTextSize();`

Изменять значение: `DataSaver.get(MyActivity.this).setTextSize(MyActivity.this, textSize);`

Можно использовать для хранения внутри приложения любых данных, кроме, пожалуй `Context` - в последнем случае возможна утечка памяти.

Можно сделать кастомный `TextView`:

```
public class MyTV extends TextView {
    public static final String PREFS = "prefs";
    public static final String T_SIZE = "size";


    public MyTV(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setTextSize(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(T_SIZE,17));
    }

    public MyTV(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyTV(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyTV(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }
}
```

установить его везде, где необходимо (единственно, в месте, где вы будете перезаписывать размер, его нужно будет перерисовывать).